# How to select a list of words instead of numbers to compute stats in Gnuplot script

Tags: gnuplot

The following script takes data from `.csv` files and compute some stats before plotting them.

```
set encoding iso_8859_1
set key left top font "Helvetica,17"
set ylabel "Lookup error probability" font "Helvetica,18"
set xlabel "Height [m]" font "Helvetica,18"

set xtics font "Helvetica,18"
set ytics font "Helvetica,18"

set terminal postscript eps enhanced color #size 6.5in,3in
set grid 
set key spacing 1.5
set output "ware_f.eps"
list(start,end,increment)=system(sprintf("seq %g %g %g", start, increment, end))

set print "ware0_f.dat"
do for [i in list(4,14,1) ] {
  stats "ware0_f.txt" u ($39==i?($54/$55):1/0) name "A" nooutput
  print i*1, A_mean,   (A_mean - 2.262*A_ssd/sqrt(A_records)),\
    (A_mean + 2.262*A_ssd/sqrt(A_records))
}

plot [][] "ware0_f.dat" using 1:2:3:4 with yerrorlines ls 2 lw 3 title "No Int."
```

The data is in file `ware0_f.txt` in this [*link*](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/po9m8ahrc8ozo37/AAAQq-qx9RVjspkXAJ4ju2uMa?dl=0).

The statistics are computed for the values of column `$39` which has numeric data (i.e. 4, 5, 6,...,14).

I want to adapt this script to values of column `$39` that are not numeric but a string of characters. The strings are "cycles_10", "cycles_20", ...., "cycles_80".

An example of a file `cycles_0.txt` with this list of strings in the column `$48` is also in the *link* above.

I would like to compute the statistics of the confidente interval using means and deviation of the values with the same `cycles` of column `$48`.

Comment: [MCVE](https://www.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) please

Comment: @Thor thanks for the comment. I have simplified the script and added the data files. One is the data file I use in this example and another file with the values I would like to use to select the data and compute the means and deviations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try:

```
# Your strings list
ListOfString = "cycle_10 cycle_20 cycle_30 cycle_40 cycle_50 cycle_60 cycle_70 cycle_80"

# Creates a datafile
set print "Data.dat"
# Loop through your list
do for [i in ListOfString]{
    # Performs stats
    stats "cycles_0.txt" u (stringcolumn(48) eq i ? ($54/$55) : 1/0 ) name "A" nooutput
    # Logical test
    if (exists("A_mean")){
        # Writes a formatted string on 'Data.dat'
        print sprintf('%s %f %f %f',\
            i,\
            A_mean,\
            (A_mean - 2.262*A_ssd/sqrt(A_records)),\
            (A_mean + 2.262*A_ssd/sqrt(A_records)))
    }
}
# Close 'Data.dat'
unset print
# Turn-off the enhanced mode on terminal
set termoption noenhanced
# put white spaces on both sides of graph
set offset 1,1
# The plot using $0 as 'x' and $1 as xlabels
plot "Data.dat" using 0:2:3:4:xticlabels(1) with yerrorlines
```

The file `Data.dat` contains:

```
cycle_10 1.486349 1.096812 1.875886
cycle_20 1.535556 1.171189 1.899922
cycle_30 0.894661 0.636397 1.152925
cycle_40 0.578156 0.396785 0.759527
cycle_50 0.246576 0.191916 0.301236
```

The results:

[image: Graph]

Comment: Thank you for your solution. May I ask you how to write just the numbers of the x-label ticks, for example 10, 20, 30, 40,... instead of cycle_10, cycle_20 and so on?.